# Express.js REST API subresources handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express

Consider the following (hopefully self-explanatory) API endpoints

```
/categories/
/categories/:cat_id
/categories/:cat_id/products
/categories/:cat_id/products/:prod_id
```

Using Express.js 4.x, I have created two different Routes to serve the aforementioned endpoints, `Categories` and `Products`. This is how I have registered them to `app`.

```
app.use('/', root); // Simple default route
app.use('/categories', categoriesRoute);
app.use('/categories/:cat_id/products', productsRoute);
```

This way, I can get `/categories/`, `/categories/:cat_id/products` and `/categories/:cat_id/products/:prod_id` to work. This is the closest I've reached. How can I register my 'Category' and 'Product' routers on `app` in a way products are parts of the categories' URL?

Comment: Assuming products are always assigned to a category, drop '/products` so you end up with `/categories/:cat_id/:prod_id`. This is, of course, dependent on your data structure.

Comment: I won't be able to get a list of each category's products, served on `/categories/:cat_id/products` though

Comment: I should have been more concise, what is shown at `/:cat_id` if not the products for the category?

Comment: On `/categories/5/products` you can see all the products of category with ID 5. On `/categories/5/products/133` you could see details of product with ID 133 of category with ID 5

Comment: So what is shown on `/categories/5`? Unless there is a use case for `/categories/5` that is vastly different than `/categories/5/products` I would drop the additional page and have both a description of the category and it's products displayed.

Comment: On `/categories/5` you can see details about category with ID 5. To be honest, this setup is used by LoopBack.io, which I'm obviously trying to replicate